# Laravel login error messages not showing via ajax in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Error messages aren't displaying when i enter wrong credentials.
I made my own routes for authentication for login.

```
// Auth::routes(); //Commented this out

// Authentication Start

Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('auth.login.get');
Route::post('submit-login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('auth.login.post');

Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('auth.register.get');
Route::post('submit-register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('auth.register.post');

// Authentication End
```

This is the ajax part

```
window.getLoginPage = function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/login',
    success:function(response) {
      $('.dynamicAuthContent').html('');
      $('.dynamicAuthContent').append(response);
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('.modalBtns').removeClass('activeAuth');
      $('.signInModal').addClass('activeAuth');
    }
  });
}
```

and this is the modal body

```
<div class="modal-body">
     <div class="dynamicAuthContent"></div>
</div>
```

This is login.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('auth.login.post') }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="bColor form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"  autocomplete="email" autofocus>

            @error('email')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="bColor form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"  autocomplete="current-password">

            @error('password')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="bColor form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn contactSubmitBtn">
                {{ __('Login') }}
            </button>

            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                </a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Everything is working fine, but my errors arent showing, when i enter wrong credentials.
But when i visit the page directly, not through ajax, error messages are visible.
I think my error messages are coming, but the modal is getting closed. How can i avoid that?

Comment: just like success function, you need to have an error function to catch errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the blade error bag with ajax because they will only get rendered when the error variable is set so in case of ajax you must call the error function same as you called the success function in ajax and in side error function you can add new DOM element to show the errors, comming .